# Which of the following are principal ideal domains

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, principal-ideal-domains

> Which of the following are principal ideal domains?
>
> (A) $\mathbb{Z}[X]/\langle X^2+1 \rangle$
>
> (B) $\mathbb{Z}[X]$
>
> (C) $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]$
>
> (D) $\mathbb{R}[X,Y]/\langle X^2+1,Y  \rangle$

My answer: (In brief)

$\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle x^2+1 \rangle$ is the ring $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ which we know is a Euclidean domain so clearly a PID.

$\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is not a PID

$\mathbb{C}[X,Y]$ is PID (for every field $F$, $F[X,Y]$ is a PID).

$\mathbb{R}[X,Y]/\langle X^2+1,Y  \rangle$ is the field $\mathbb{C}$ which is a PID.

Can anyone please critique my answers. Thanks.

Comment: All correct except (C), $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]$ is not a PID, consider the ideal generated by $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Or also consider that its krull dimension is $2$, where a PID  has krull dimension $1$ or $0$

Comment: What it's true is that for every field $F$, $F[X, Y]$ is a UFD (this follows easily from Gauss' theorem for UFDs).

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in each, for valid reasons, except for part $C)$, as mentioned in the comments.

If $A$ is a field, then $A[x]$ is a PID, and the converse holds. However, when $B$ is only a PID (and not a field), it is not the case that $B[x]$ will be a PID.

Here, I mean to say that $B=A[y]$ being a PID doesn't make $B[x]\cong A[x,y]$ a PID. If it did, then due to our converse $A[y]$ would be a field.